# Device throws a ConstraintException error when logged in with Facebook

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, devise

I'm using device so that users can register and log in through my app. But I would also like to have user log in through Facebook.

User can register and log in now, but when they log in through Facebook I get an error.

```
SQLite3::ConstraintException: NOT NULL constraint failed: 
users.email: INSERT INTO "users" 
("provider", "uid", "email", "encrypted_password", "name", "last_sign_in_at", "current_sign_in_at", "last_sign_in_ip", "current_sign_in_ip", "sign_in_count") 
VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

User.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable,:omniauthable, :omniauth_providers => [:facebook]

  def self.from_omniauth(auth)
    where(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid).first_or_create do |user|
      user.email = auth.info.email
      user.password = Devise.friendly_token[0,20]
      user.name = auth.info.name   # assuming the user model has a name
    end
  end
end
```

callbacks_controller.rb

```
class CallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController
    def facebook
        @user = User.from_omniauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"])
        sign_in_and_redirect @user
    end
end
```

schema.rb

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20150731102008) do

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "email",                  default: "", null: false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "", null: false
    t.string   "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0,  null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.string   "provider"
    t.string   "uid"
    t.string   "name"
  end

  add_index "users", ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
  add_index "users", ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true

end
```

Answer (score 1):

this is happen as you male `null: false` constraint in migration.

Plese change the email column to null: true

```
create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "email",                  default: "", null: true
    t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "", null: true
    t.string   "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0,  null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.string   "provider"
    t.string   "uid"
    t.string   "name"
  end
```

Comment: The problem with this solution is that when a user signs in through Facebook nog email adres is saved, which I would like to save.

Answer (score 1):

You don't always get a email address when authenticating with facebook. Users can actually accept your app and still deny email even if you are asking for `scope=email`.

You can still assign the users a `username@facebook.com` address. All facebook users have one. The key difference is that you actually send them a Facebook message, instead of regular email.

```
def self.from_omniauth(auth)
  where(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid).first_or_create do |user|
    user.email = auth.info.email || "#{auth.info.nickname}@facebook.com"
    user.password = Devise.friendly_token[0,20]
    user.name = auth.info.name   # assuming the user model has a name
  end
end
```

Comment: It seems you have a small typo since I get a `undefined method `com' for nil:NilClass` error in this line `user.email = auth.info.email || "#{auth.info.nickname@facebook.com}"`

Comment: Ah, yes, sorry. There was a closing brace missing - thats what happens when you type code in the browser... I have edited the answer.

Comment: I still think this is a better idea than changing your database schema - especially since Devise in many cases uses the email column as a primary identifier.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why it works, but I found the solution here https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/issues/588

I changed my migration file,

```
t.string :email,              null: true, default: ""
t.string :encrypted_password, null: true, default: ""
```

These were false, I set them to true.

```
# add_index :users, :email,                unique: true
# add_index :users, :reset_password_token, unique: true
# add_index :users, :confirmation_token,   unique: true
# add_index :users, :unlock_token,         unique: true
```

And I commented these.

Now I can log in through Facebook and through the app itself.

Answer (score 0):

In the end the solution was found here > https://github.com/mkdynamic/omniauth-facebook/issues/61 near the bottom. I had to inlcude the scope and include part into my devise.rb

```
config.omniauth :facebook, 'id', 'secret',scope: 'public_profile,email', info_fields: 'email,name'
```

Now my Facebook email is saved in the database. This is not a 100% proof way though, since some Facebook users use their phone number as login.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your Facebook account doesn't have an email address.
If you add your email(or other parameters) in Facebook(facebook.com/settings),
it should be working!